# Set HttpMessageHandler to an instance of HttpClient after initialization

Tags: asp.net-web-api, httpclient

I want to share an instance of `HttpClient` between different requests and it seems fortunately this class is safe to be used cuncurrently.

But I need to set `HttpMessageHandler` for each individual request since they may have different ClientCertificates. Apparently this can only be done via constructor and not available after initialization!

Any idea how to set this property after initialization? or a workaround?

Comment: I'm wondering if you solved this issue. I have something very similar.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use WebRequestHandler as a handler added to HttpClient constructor, keep its reference and then change certificates on per request basis.
this link might help: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/henrikn/2012/08/07/httpclient-httpclienthandler-and-webrequesthandler-explained/

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly setting it after instantiation, but would this approach work in your case?

```cs
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;


public abstract class MyHttpClient : HttpClient
{
    protected MyHttpClient() : base(new HttpClientHandler { AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate })
    {
        DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));
        DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptCharset.Add(StringWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("UTF-8"));
        DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(StringWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("gzip"));
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't "connect" the HttpClient and the injected Handler. The handler can only be specified in a constructor of HttpClient. So this doesn't offer a solution.