# How to put HttpClientHandler and SocketsHttpHandler into HttpClient

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

HttpClient accepts only one HttpMessageHandler. I have two of them.

```
HttpClientHandler clientHandler = GetClientHandler();
SocketsHttpHandler socketsHandler = GetSocketsHandler();
HttpClient client = new( /* how to put two handlers here? */ );
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set HttpMessageHandler to an instance of HttpClient after initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37066711/set-httpmessagehandler-to-an-instance-of-httpclient-after-initialization)

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: @ChristianO. no, I'm afraid it's not what I'm looking for

Comment: @ggeorge socketHandler makes requests from different ip-addresses on my server and clientHandler automatically decompresses responses.

Answer (score 1):

At least for .NET 6+, when looking at the source code of [HttpClientHandler](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/35fe82c2e90fa345d0b6ad243c14da193fb123fd/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClientHandler.cs), one can see that under the covers, this class simply uses a `SocketsHttpHandler` and maps most properties 1-to-1.  So, you can just use a `SocketsHttpHandler` yourself and set all the same properties.  See the source code for reference on any custom logic that the `HttpClientHandler` may be doing that you may want to consider doing against the `SocketsHttpHandler`.

Further comments from folks at Microsoft can be seen [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/issues/1961), encouraging use of `SocketsHttpHandler`.